# How to iterate through several api calls and several dictionnary keys in the same time?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

Here is my problem :
I need to call this API > https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-api.

My goal is to get in a dataframe the daily forecast weather on the next 7 seven days for a list of specific cities (based on their GPS coordinates). I need to iterate through 35 cities but here is a sample with 2 cities and a static way to get the keys a need.

A example of call for one city and containing the info for the next 7 days :

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=48.6355232&lon=-1.5102571&exclude=hourly,current,minutely&appid=be02e7c76c38ec4e28e37a166d60abb7

So I have done that for the moment :

```
import requests

url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall"
lat = ["48.6355232", "47.3215806"]
lon = ["-1.5102571", "5.0414701"]
output_results = []
for lat,lon in zip(lat, lon):
    r = requests.get(url, params={"lat":lat, "lon":lon, "exclude":"hourly,current,minutely", "appid":"be02e7c76c38ec4e28e37a166d60abb7"})
    output_results.append(r.json())


print(output_results[0]["lat"]) #latitude
print(output_results[0]["lon"]) #longitude
print(output_results[0]["daily"][0]["dt"]) #date
print(output_results[0]["daily"][0]["temp"]["day"]) #temperature
print(output_results[0]["daily"][0]["wind_speed"]) #wind speed
print(output_results[0]["daily"][0]["clouds"]) # clouds density
```

How could I iterate through the coordinates list AND the keys I need ?

I would like to structure my final dataframe this way :
[df structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FmDA.png)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think your problem is a bit unclear. Do you need to use a new api key, from a list, for each request?

Comment: You already seem to be iterating over the coordinates list. After each *get()* you are appending a reference to a JSON object to your output_results list. You just need to iterate over that once you've acquired the outputs from your various queries. On another note, if you have a lot of coordinates to process, you should probably think about multithreading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're hoping to achieve:-

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall"
lat = ["48.6355232", "47.3215806"]
lon = ["-1.5102571", "5.0414701"]
params = {"exclude": "hourly,current,minutely",
          "appid": "be02e7c76c38ec4e28e37a166d60abb7"}
columns = ['Date', 'Latitude', 'Longitude',
           'Temperature', 'Wind speed', 'Clouds']
DATA = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    for lat, lon in zip(lat, lon):
        params['lat'] = lat
        params['lon'] = lon
        r = session.get(url, params=params)
        r.raise_for_status()
        d = r.json()['daily'][0]
        dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(d['dt']).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        DATA.append([dt, lat, lon, d['temp']['day'],
                    d['wind_speed'], d['clouds']])
df = pd.DataFrame(DATA, columns=columns)
print(df)
```